# Angular 4: how to use Select element to switch between different visualisations in Mapbox?

Tags: angular, mapbox

I'm working on an angular 4 project using Mapbox to make a dashboard that displays different visualisations with different styles, so the user can switch between different styles for the map and also between many visualisations to display the data (geoJson format) in different ways.
What I try to do is to make a select element that helps to switch between the visualisations (I did the same thing for the map styles) but I can't do it.
Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div id='map'></div>
    <div id='geocoder' class='geocoder'>
    </div>
    <div id='styles'>
      <select id='style' name='style' class='select-option' [(ngModel)]="style" (ngModelChange)="changeStyle($event)">
        <option id='sty' *ngFor="let l of styleList" [value]="l.value" [ngValue]="undefined" selected> {{l.value}} </option >
      </select>
    </div>
   <select id='layer' name='layer'>
    <option id='markers' class='select-option' value="markers" (ngModelChange)="addHeatmaps($event)">Markers</option>
    <option id='heatmaps' class='select-option' value="heatmaps" (ngModelChange)="colorHeatmaps($event)">Heatmaps</option>
    <option id='dotdensity' class='select-option' value="dotdensity" (ngModelChange)="dotLayer($event)">Dot density</option>
    <option id='clusters' class='select-option' value="clusters" (ngModelChange)="clusterLayer($event)">Clusters</option>
    <option id='hexbins' class='select-option' value="hexbins" (ngModelChange)="hexbinsLayer($event)">Hexbins</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And here is my component.ts:

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  public map: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  public styleList: Array<Object> = [
    { id: 'basic', value: 'Basic' },
    { id: 'streets', value: 'Streets' },
    { id: 'bright', value: 'Bright' },
    { id: 'light', value: 'Light' },
    { id: 'dark', value: 'Dark' },
    { id: 'satellite', value: 'Satellite' }
  ];
  public visualisations: Array<Object> = [
    { id: 'markers', value: 'Markers' },
    { id: 'heatmaps', value: 'Heatmaps' },
    { id: 'dotdensity', value: 'Dot density' },
    { id: 'clusters', value: 'Clusters' },
    { id: 'hexbins', value: 'Hexbins' }
  ];
  public style = this.styleList[0].id;
  public vis = this.visualisations[0];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init('basic')
  }
  changeStyle(data) {
    console.log("data", data)
    this.init(data.toLowerCase())
  }
  init(type) {
    var map;
    console.log("map", map)
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'myToken';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
      center: [16.05, 48],
      zoom: 6
    });

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());
    let self = this;
    map.on('load', function () {
      addHeatmaps();
      switchLayer()
      function switchLayer() {
        var layerId = self.style.toLowerCase();    
        map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/' + layerId + '-v9');
        var visualisation = self.vis;
        setTimeout(() => {
          SwitchVisualisation(visualisation);
        }, 1000);
      }

      function SwitchVisualisation(visualisation) {
        switch (visualisation) {
          case "markers": {
            map.addHeatmaps();
            break;
          }
          case "heatmaps": {
            map.colorHeatmaps();
            break;
          }
          case "dotdensity": {
            map.dotLayer();
            break;
          }
          case "clusters": {
            map.clusterLayer();
            break;
          }
          case "hexbins": {
            map.hexbinsLayer();
            break;
          }
          default: {
            console.log("Invalid choice");
            break;
          }
        }
      }

    });

    function addHeatmaps() {
      console.log(heatmaps);
    };


    function colorHeatmaps() {
      console.log(color);
    }
    function clusterLayer() {
      console.log(cluster);
    }
    function dotLayer() {
      console.log(dot);
    }
    function hexbinsLayer() {
      console.log(hexbins);
    }

    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000').subscribe(data => {
      // using the HttpClient instance, http to call the API then subscribe to the data and display to console
      console.log(data);

    },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log('Client-side error occured.');
        } else {
          console.log('Server-side error occured.');
        }
      });
  }
```

I tried many things but I'm missing something, your help is really appreciated.

Comment: can you explain what is the error are your facing ? I am not sure what is the obstacle in your code.

Comment: and maybe use `[ngModel]="style"` instead of `[(ngModel)]="style"` because you already using `ngModelChange`

Comment: Now I'm working on the element: <div id='list'> which is related to the function SwitchVisualisation(), there's no error but the visualisation is not changing, It only displays the first visualisation from the switch list.

Comment: @emostafa do you have an idea why It's not going through the switch element? It only reads the first function

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that i noticed in your code,

First of all you are using `(ngModelChange)="addHeatmaps($event)` on the option tags, not on the selected tag, use the same pattern that you have used the with the select map tag. If you don't want to use ngModel you can just use `(change)="layerChanged($event)"`

e.g:

```
<select id='layer' name='layer' (change)="layerChanged($event)">
```

I think you don't need to write `[ngValue]="undefined"` just use the `[value]` attr, and there is no need for `selected` since this will be resolved using the ngModel value.

Comment: Now I tried this: <div id='list'>
  <select id='layer' name='layer' class='select-option' (change)= "SwitchVisualisation($event)">
      <option id='vis' *ngFor="let v of visualisations" [value]="v.value"> {{v.value}} </option>
    </select>
  </div> But after every clic on one of the elements get this error: MapComponent.html:11 ERROR TypeError: _co.SwitchVisualisation is not a function

Comment: that's because you have defined the SwitchVisualisation inside `map.on('load'...)` under `init` function, so it's not accessible directly, you should move it to be in the root of the component instead. That goes for the other functions too, you defined all of them in side the `init`, that might work, but the best practice is to have them in the root of the component.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I did the changes and It's working now. But the lists doesn't display a default value.

Comment: in your option tags, you have `[value]="l.value"` this should be `[value]="l.id"` because the value you are passing to ngModel is and id, here: `public style = this.styleList[0].id;`

Comment: Thank you so much, It's working as I want it to be, thank you.

Comment: That's great, would you like to select my answer as correct one?